Replace some value in a csv file in ADLS gen 2
I ADLS gen 2 location I have some csv file. in that csv file there are some value are like 03-01-24 9:47:45 PM, so I want only 03-01-24 value only. so I want a pyspark code which i can run from databricks and replace the value in csv file itself. don't create any other file, i want it should be done in the same original file itself

StackOverflow requires you to attempt to solve your coding problem yourself. If you get stuck with specific problem you may ask for our help, providing the code you have tried. Right now, you are asking for a complete script showing no effort from your side. So please, give it a try and we will assist from there.

Using Pyspark it is not possible to write into same file in data bricks, alternatively you can use python.

With PySpark, you cannot write a modified Spark DataFrame back into the original file. Instead, you can use the Pandas library in Databricks. Here's a sample CSV file:



id
timestamp
value




1
03-01-24 9:47:45 PM
10


2
03-01-24 10:15:32 AM
15


3
03-01-25 2:30:00 PM
20


4
03-01-26 11:59:59 PM
25


5
03-01-27 6:45:12 AM
30



To read the CSV file, mount the ADLS account using the code below:
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source="wasbs://<containerName>@<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point="/mnt/<mountName>",
    extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":"<Access-Key>"  
  }
)

Read the CSV file and modify it according to the requirement using the code below:
df = pd.read_csv("/dbfs/mnt/<mountName>/input.csv")
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].str.split().str[0]
print(df)

Here is the modified DataFrame:



id
timestamp
value




1
03-01-24
10


2
03-01-24
15


3
03-01-25
20


4
03-01-26
25


5
03-01-27
30



Write the modified DataFrame into the original file using the code below:
df.to_csv("/dbfs/mnt/<mountName>/input.csv", index=False) 

This will write to the original file successfully. Here's the complete code for your reference:
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv("/dbfs/mnt/<mountName>/input.csv")
# Splitting timestamp to date only
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].str.split().str[0]
print(df)
# Write back to the same file
df.to_csv("/dbfs/mnt/<mountName>/input.csv", index=False)


@Swarnava Sen Please check if the solution helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
